# How to bind object property in ListView from another ListView

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvm

i am writing xamarin forecast weather app with MVVM.

I fill `ObservableCollection<DailyWeather>` and `ObservableCollection<HourlyWeather>`.

In ViewModel

```
private ObservableCollection<DailyWeather> dailyWeather;

        public ObservableCollection<DailyWeather> DailyWeather
        {
            get => dailyWeather;
            set
            {
                dailyWeather = value;
                OnPropertyChange();
            }
        }
```

Models

```
public class DailyWeather
    {
        public int DayOfYear { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<HourlyWeather> HourlyWeather { get; set; }

    }
```

```
public class HourlyWeather
    {
        public string Temperature { get; set; }
        public string Time { get; set; }
    }
```

Xaml code

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding DailyWeather, Source={StaticResource vm}}"
          RowHeight="200">

                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <StackLayout>

                                <Label Text="{Binding DayOfYear}"/>

                                <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding HourlyWeather}">
                                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            
                                             <ViewCell>
                                                <StackLayout>
                                                    <Label Text="{Binding Temperature}"/>
                                                    <Label Text="{Binding Time}"/>
                                                </StackLayout>
                                            </ViewCell>

                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                </ListView>

                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
               </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Parent ListView outputs collection and "DayOfYear".

Child ListView Outputs Collection and sees object properties "Temperature" and "Time" but not output them, why?

All collections are filled.

Why if i delete ViewCell from ListViews then app thow "specified cast is not valid" exception?

Comment: ListView accepts only ViewCell as ItemTemplate, otherwise you get specified cast not valid.

Comment: Please accept the answer which is works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove this **Source={StaticResource vm}** from your binding.

Add this to your XAML:

```
 <ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <vm:VIEWMODEL></vm:VIEWMODEL>
</ContentPage.BindingContext>
```

And change parent listview to this:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding DailyWeather}" RowHeight="200">
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `Source={StaticResource vm}` in ItemSource of your ListView. And set the code below in the code behind of your page.

```
   this.BindingContext = this;
```

**The whole code:**

```
  public partial class Page1 : ContentPage
{
    private ObservableCollection<DailyWeather> dailyWeather;

    public ObservableCollection<DailyWeather> DailyWeather
    {
        get => dailyWeather;
        set
        {
            dailyWeather = value;

        }
    }
    public Page1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DailyWeather = new ObservableCollection<DailyWeather>()
        {
            new DailyWeather()
            {
                 DayOfYear=2011,
                  HourlyWeather=new ObservableCollection<HourlyWeather>()
                  {
                      new HourlyWeather()
                      {
                           Temperature="1",
                            Time="2011-01-02"
                      },
                      new HourlyWeather()
                      {
                            Temperature="2",
                            Time="2011-01-03"
                      },
                       new HourlyWeather()
                      {
                           Temperature="3",
                            Time="2011-01-04"
                      },
                      new HourlyWeather()
                      {
                            Temperature="4",
                            Time="2011-01-05"
                      }
                  }
            }
        };
        this.BindingContext = this;
    }
}
public class DailyWeather
{
    public int DayOfYear { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<HourlyWeather> HourlyWeather { get; set; }

}
public class HourlyWeather
{
    public string Temperature { get; set; }
    public string Time { get; set; }
}
```

**Screenshot:**

[image: enter code here]

Comment: i using MVVM pattern so this answer dont useful for me...

Answer (score 0):

If you using mvvm , you should use Locator. Here is working example. Changed some tags because dont have WPF now at pc.

YourVM.cs

```
class YourVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private ObservableCollection<DailyWeather> dailyWeather;

        public ObservableCollection<DailyWeather> DailyWeather
        {
            get => dailyWeather;
            set
            {
                dailyWeather = value;
                OnPropertyChange(nameof(DailyWeather));
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void OnPropertyChange(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        public YourVM()
        {
            DailyWeather = new ObservableCollection<DailyWeather>()
            {
                new DailyWeather()
                {
                     DayOfYear=2011,
                      HourlyWeather=new ObservableCollection<HourlyWeather>()
                      {
                          new HourlyWeather()
                          {
                               Temperature="1",
                                Time="2011-01-02"
                          },
                          new HourlyWeather()
                          {
                                Temperature="2",
                                Time="2011-01-03"
                          },
                           new HourlyWeather()
                          {
                               Temperature="3",
                                Time="2011-01-04"
                          },
                          new HourlyWeather()
                          {
                                Temperature="4",
                                Time="2011-01-05"
                          }
                      }
                }
            };
        }
    }
```

MVVMLocator.cs

```
class MVVMLocator
    {
        public MVVMLocator()
        {
            ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<YourVM>();
        }

        public static YourVM YourVM => SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<YourVM>();
    }
```

App.xaml

```
<Application
    x:Class="App2.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App2">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <local:MVVMLocator x:Key="Locator"/>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

MainPage.xaml

```
<Page
    x:Class="App2.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding YourVM.DailyWeather , Source={StaticResource Locator}}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Height="200">

                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding DayOfYear}"/>

                        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding HourlyWeather}">
                            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Temperature}"/>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Time}"/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListView>

                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Nuget: CommonServiceLocator , MvvmLightLibs